# C++ Loop Outputs Average From Set of Numbers With Decimals

Tags: loops

Beginner C++ student here, first programming class. I am trying to build a program which will accept a set of numbers from the user and output the average.  However, when attempting to get the average of example 1 I get 3.5. Example two I get -0. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Examples:

Output the average of the values entered.

Example 1: A run of your program might go as

```
1  2  3  4  blah

2.5
```

Example 2: A run of your program might go as

```
blah

no data
```

`#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


double num;
double input;
double sum = 0;
double avg;

cout << "Please enter a set of numbers. Enter a non-number to quit: "
  << endl;
cin >> num;

while (cin >> num) // When value is not a number, quit.

for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){

  cin >> input;
  sum += input;
}

avg = sum / num;
cout << "average = " << avg << endl;

return 0;

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Put together a different type of loop which works better in this scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // exit EXIT_FAILURE

using namespace std;

bool die(const string & msg);

int main(){

int numToEnter;
double sum = 0;
double average = 0;
double input;

// Get numbers from the user

cout << "Enter number of items: ";
cin >> numToEnter || die("Input failure, only numbers allowed.");

while ((cout << "Enter a number: ") && (cin >> input))

{

    int i = 1;
    i <= numToEnter;

    sum += input;

}

// Get average and print it
average = sum / numToEnter;

cout << "The average is: " << average << endl;

return 0;
}

bool die(const string & msg)

{
cout << "Fatal Error: " << msg << endl;

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```